# How create template functions where both the container and the type are parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

This might be a trivial question but is driving me crazy.
I want to define a single function `foo()` that would work with different containers like:
`vector<int>`, `vector<double>`, `set<int>` and `set<double>`.

I have tried to define foo like this:

```
template<typename CONT, typename T>
   int foo(CONT<T>){
      //evaluate x
      return (int) x ;
   }
```

This kind of definition doesn't work, but I can't understand why.

How can I achieve something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to specify both the container class template and its instantiation is to use template template parameters:

```
template <template <typename...> class Cont, typename T>
int foo(Cont<T>) {
    ...
}
```

Note that `Cont` is using a variable number of arguments because otherwise it wouldn't cover the unknown number of defaulted template arguments the standard containers have.

Comment: This may be the first time I have ever actually understood a template template parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this:

```
template< class ContainerT >
int foo( ContainerT const& c ) {
}
```

Then `ContainerT` can be any thing, including `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<std::string>` or even `std::map<std::string, int>`. So you don't need to add a new template parameter and if you need to know the type just use `value_type` of your container:

```
typedef typename ContainerT::value_type container_type; // Or T in your foo
```